# RabbitMQ consumer problem in C# with Win Forms - Message consumed but not shown

Tags: c#, winforms, rabbitmq, producer-consumer, rabbitmq-exchange

I managed to properly create a sender and the messages to be sent to RabbitMQ, but when setting up the consumer with the method given above, all it does is to consume the message, the richtextbox control is not updated, i also cant see the message in Console. I tried to call the method at form load event and the click button event, same result, message is consumed from server but no return on the interface

```cs
        public async Task GetMessages()
        {
            try
            {
                var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
                {
                    HostName = "localhost",
                    UserName = "guest",
                    Password = "guest"
                };
                using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "administrator_queue", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

                    var consumer = new AsyncEventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                    channel.BasicConsume(queue: "administrator_queue", autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);
                    consumer.Received += async (eventSender, eventArgs) =>
                    {
                        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventArgs.Body.ToArray());
                        var currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

                        await Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                            {
                                richTextBox.AppendText($"{currentDate}: {message}\n");
                            });
                        });

                        Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {currentDate}: {message}");
                    };
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The types are being disposed (by `using`) before the message is received. Try storing them as member variables instead.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to this. Do u mean just removing the using or creating methods like these.: public void InitializeConnectionFactory()
    {factory = new ConnectionFactory()
        {       HostName = "localhost",
            UserName = "guest",
            Password = "guest"};}
    public void EstablishConnection()
    { connection = factory.CreateConnection();}
    public void CreateChannel()
    { channel = connection.CreateModel();
    } . I also tried to create a separate consumer class, same problem. I think I'm misunderstanding something in this logic. Thanks a lot

Comment: You could do it that way, yes.

Comment: Tried it, same problem.

Comment: Please post a minimal repro with the new code.

Comment: @DenT - really, you can't expect anyone to assist you without providing code to demonstrate  the issue. It is a simple thing to create a public git repository.